# Cannot convert call result type 'Set<String>' to expected type 'String' error

Tags: macos-catalina, swift4.2

I am working on an old Swift 3 project and I'm getting this error after updating it to Swift 4.2. It seems to work fine in Swift 3. I had to declare `let NSURLPboardType = NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(kUTTypeURL as String)` because NSURLPboardType does not exist in Swift 4.2 but otherwise the code is the same.

```
enum SparkleDrag {
    static let type = "com.razeware.StickerDrag.AppAction"
    static let action = "make sparkles"
}

let NSURLPboardType = NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(kUTTypeURL as String)
  
var nonURLTYpes: Set<String> {return [String(kUTTypeTIFF), SparkleDrag.type]}
  
var acceptableTypes: Set<String> {return [nonURLTYpes.union(NSURLPboardType)]}
```

The "u" in `union` is underlined with the error but I don't quite understand the nature of the problem. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: You don't need these `returns` btw, you can just write: `var nonURLTYpes: Set<String> { [String(kUTTypeTIFF), SparkleDrag.type] }`. It also doesn't look like these really need to be computed, you could just simplify further to `var nonURLTYpes: Set<String> = [String(kUTTypeTIFF), SparkleDrag.type]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `NSURLPboardType` is not a `Set<String>`, so the union cannot work.

If you're trying to get something like this:

```
["com.razeware.StickerDrag.AppAction", "public.url", "public.tiff"]
```

in `aceptableTypes`, you can simply forgo `NSURLPboardType` and do this:

```
enum SparkleDrag {
    static let type = "com.razeware.StickerDrag.AppAction"
    static let action = "make sparkles"
}

// let NSURLPboardType = NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(kUTTypeURL as String)
  
var nonURLTYpes: Set<String> {return [String(kUTTypeTIFF), SparkleDrag.type]}
  
var acceptableTypes: Set<String> {return nonURLTYpes.union([kUTTypeURL as String])}
```

Comment: @ tromgy Thank you for that answer. That Set was exactly what I was trying to get.